# linq - use property from parent object within Any() call

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Say I have the following kind of object structure: (I don't of course, it's just an example)

```
public class Man
{
  public Woman Wife { get; set; }
  public List<Animal> Pets { get; set; }
}
public class Woman
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Animal
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a Linq predicate which determines whether a `Man` owns a pet with the same name as his wife.

I can't work out how to do this, because when I write the `x.Pets.Any(...)` bit, I'm now working with `Pet` objects and I have no way to reference the parent `Man`'s `Wife` property.

[Edit: the above statement is incorrect. It was a false assumption.]

Is there a way I can structure this predicate to get the logic I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var query = men.Where(man => man.Pets.Any(pet => pet.Name == man.Wife.Name));
```

Comment: For some reason, I totally thought the man variable would be out of scope. I have egg on my face.

Comment: @David Why close it? It's a good question that someone else might find useful later one.

Comment: Because it was based on a false assumption. But if it's useful, hey, keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have one man with one wife so you can do:

```
var hasPetNamedLikeWife = MyMan.Pets.Any(x => x.Name == MyMan.Wife.Name);
```

Mind you I strongly recommend against marrying a woman called fido ;-)